# Dual Boot - Windows stopped working, now It doesn't show up anymore

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair

For a while, I've used dual boot with windows 10 on my SSD and Ubuntu (18.04) on my HDD. At start I have the GRUB menu where I can select whether I want to boot on Ubuntu or Windows. I mainly use Ubuntu but I need windows from time to time.

For some reason I've tried running windows and it was not working:

```
error: no such device: AA58-CC17
error: disk "hd1, gpt1" not available
```

So I've installed boot-repair on my hdd and I used the repair function, things are it did not work. Not only it did not work, but also it removed windows from my boot options. I've tried again by running boot-repair on a live ubuntu session but things did not change, windows don't show up anymore.

So I'm guessing that windows is still there on my SSD, but boot-repair removed it showing up on GRUB after finding that the link to it was broken. It's not in the UEFI anymore, I don't know if it was appearing prior to the boot-repair reparation

Do you have an idea on where the problem comes from and how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: does the bios still detect the SSD?

Comment: Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: Here is the boot-repair report: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Jqk4cTNj9t/

No, the BIOS doesn't seem to detect the SSD anymore, I don't know if it did prior to using boot-repair